Python Beautifulsoup craw original image from google search image
My issue is when I craw image from google image search, the result I received is thumbnail image with poor resolution.
Do you have any to craw original image ?
This is my code that I used:
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
        images = soup.find_all('img')
        
        current_number = self.start_number
        
        for img_element in tqdm(images, desc="Downloading images"):
            try:
                if img_element is None:
                    continue
                img_url = img_element.get('src', '')
                response = requests.get(img_url)
                img_content = response.content

Please help !
Can craw original image with high resolution

Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].
